# What are the steps for revoking Malaysian citizenship?

Tags: citizenship, malaysia

I have a question regarding the revocation of Malaysian citizenship

Is the final stage to revoke a person’s citizenship through preliminary investigation from a committee report?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, no. On [Refworld](https://www.refworld.org/docid/47d6546928.html) it states about revoking your own citizenship voluntarily:

> The process for renunciation of citizenship requires applicants to complete an application, "Form K", and to submit this to the nearest Malaysian Embassy or High Commission together with the following: original current Malaysian passport; original Malaysian identity card; original Malaysian birth certificate (which will be returned to the applicant once the renunciation process is completed); copy of the citizenship certificate obtained from another country; two passport photos; and a fee of five Canadian dollars (Malaysia 23 Oct. 2007; Malaysia n.d.g).

This means that no investigation is required when you revoke your own citizenship. However, Refworld also states that you can lose your citizenship involuntarily, but does not state the steps for this to happen, so I cannot say for sure what the steps for that would be.

The trustworthiness of Refworld: On [this site](https://undatacatalog.org/dataset/refworld) they say that Refworld is run by the [UNHCR](https://www.unhcr.org/en-us/), which according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_Nations_organizations) is a subsect of the UN. This means that Refworld is trustworthy.